# Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf creating error with template

Tags: perl, pdf-generation, catalyst

I am using Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf but issues are araising, 
got the error

```
Caught exception in wealthe::View::Wkhtmltopdf->process "Void-input at /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/View/Wkhtmltopdf.pm line 98."
```

When checked found its some issue with template, I have added the following config in myapp.pm

```
 'View::Wkhtmltopdf' => { command => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
                             tmpdir => '/usr/tmp',
                             tt_view => 'TT', 
                           }
```

Template name is TT.pm under View and TT.pm is rendering correctly, 
I have made Wkhtmltopdf.pm file under View with the following contents

```
package myapp::View::Wkhtmltopdf; 
use Moose; 
extends qw/Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf/; 
PACKAGE->meta->make_immutable();
```

is there anything else I need to get it working.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=pdf.. use this link

Comment: Your repeated references to TT.pm rendering correctly concern me. Templates are generally .tt or .tt2 files that are interpreted by the Template Toolkit engine. If C::V::Wkh is expecting a .tt file and not getting it, perhaps that explains why it reports void input?

Comment: In myapp/View folder I have TT.pm whose content is package myapp::View::TT;
use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::View::TT';
__PACKAGE__->config(TEMPLATE_EXTENSION => '.tt');

Comment: Is that the template file you are talking about? I have my .tt files inside root/templates folder. Can you say which template file should be added in the config?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to create a (quite simple) HTML page then convert it to PDF: https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::FromHTML

It needs the least amount of PDF knowledge.

The other module could create PDF on the fly but they are much more complicated: https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the PDF writing perl modules on CPAN is that every option is either:

- extremely simple, but capable of only very rudimentary output
- fully featured and capable of professional PDF output, but hideously complex and requiring pretty deep knowledge of PDF internals

We gave up.

Instead of trying to generate PDFs with perl natively from scratch, we attacked the problem by building the pages we wanted to render as PDF with Template Toolkit (in most cases reusing existing templates with different wrappers), and used the excellent [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to handle the conversion to PDF.

Since then, [Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aWkhtmltopdf) has become available that makes this even simpler.

Comment: I am using  Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf  but issues are araising, got the error 
 Caught exception in wealthe::View::Wkhtmltopdf->process "Void-input at /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst/View/Wkhtmltopdf.pm line 98."
When checked found its some issue with template, I have added the following code
'View::Wkhtmltopdf' => {
          command   => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
          # Guessed via File::Spec by default
          tmpdir    => '/usr/tmp',
          # Name of the Template view, "TT" by default
          tt_view   => 'TT',
Template name is TT.pm under View

Comment: Does your template render OK to the browser? Make sure that works properly first, then reroute it through Wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Yep the TT.pm is rendering , I have made Wkhtmltopdf.pm file  under View with the following contents 
package wealthe::View::Wkhtmltopdf;
    
use Moose;
extends qw/Catalyst::View::Wkhtmltopdf/;
    
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable();

And also in myapp.pm added the config
__PACKAGE__->config(  'View::Wkhtmltopdf' => {
          command   => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
          # Guessed via File::Spec by default
          tmpdir    => '/usr/tmp',
          # Name of the Template view, "TT" by default
          tt_view   => 'TT',
      }, );
is there anything else I need to do

Comment: You should update your original question and show your code there so it's readable. What's in your comments is not sufficient to help you debug the problem.